# Azure Service Bus errors

Tags: azureservicebus

I've been experimenting with the latest Azure Service Bus SDK. Using very low-volume topic messages (posted by manually-executed Azure Function HTTP triggers from my browser), I'm seeing a pretty high failure rate in the Azure dashboard -- something like one out of every four or five messages fails. However, I don't ever catch any exceptions in the Azure Function code. How is a sending application supposed to detect these failures? For that matter, how do I log the specific failures? I see the spikes in the graph but can't find details. (I'm using an MSDN VS Enterprise freebie subscription.) Sometimes the queued messages and/or failures don't show up in the Azure portal for several minutes. (So far I haven't written a subscriber but I'm guessing the portal is effectively a "subscribe to everything" client of some kind.)

The topic is non-partitioned with a long TTL (the 14-day default). No dupe detection. The code is simple enough (try/catch omitted), newevent is a simple C# class with just a couple of properties and ToString is an override using JsonConvert:

```
        TopicClient topic = new TopicClient(connection, topic);
        Message msg = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newevent.ToString()));
        msg.MessageId = newevent.Timestamp;
        await topic.SendAsync(msg);
        await topic.CloseAsync();
```

Comment: Please add more details about failure - where you see them, any additional info like error text etc.

Comment: As stated earlier, I see error counts in the Portal, and no exceptions are triggered so I can't tell you what the errors are.

Comment: A few more slow-fire tests (one hit every few seconds) and I'm falling below a 50% success rate. Five messages received and delivered out of 12 actually sent -- and still no exceptions at the sender. (I only just now added a subscriber for test purposes, which is why all the deliveries happened at once.)

![portal](https://i.imgur.com/DqoDe65.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a blocker for low-volume traffic, but you shouldn't new up and close your `TopicClient` for each message. You can create it once and reuse for subsequent requests.

In the context of Azure Functions, you are better off using output binding feature instead of creating `TopicClient` yourself, see example in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus). The runtime will manage topic client for you then.

Comment: Good point about bindings, and you answered another question I didn't ask -- `TopicClient` connection is slow and there is no Function lifecycle (events, disposal, etc) to manage `AsyncClose`. I've been so focused on writing pre-built code that I ignored that feature of Functions. Technically the service bus messages are more of a side-effect (they aren't the primary work-product of the Functions), so it "feels" a little wrong to me to put them in the contract, but I will try it anyway.

Comment: One immediate problem I'm seeing switching to the binding approach is that my async HTTP Function can't use out parameters, which leaves me dependent on `ICollector<T>` ... which means I can't access the message properties. Maybe I'm overthinking it -- is it safe to never close `TopicClient`?

Comment: It should be safe. But ICollector can work with BrokeredMessage too.